# Dimethyltryptamine and Sigma 1-type opioid receptor interaction

Tags: proteins, pharmacology, hallucinogens, pharmacodynamics

Where exactly do dimethyltryptamine and sigma 1-type opioid receptor interact? I read in this [When the Endogenous Hallucinogenic Trace Amine N,N-Dimethyltryptamine Meets the Sigma-1 Receptor](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3155724/#!po=31.8182) but it does not say where exactly they interact only that they do.

Answer (score 1):

From your article:

> Sig-1Rs localize at the interface between the endoplasmic reticulum (ER) and mitochondrion, which is known as the mitochondria-associated ER membrane (MAM).

Consequently, they are found in a variety of areas within the central nervous system as well as in other types of cells throughout the body (notably cardiac cells).

> An important biological activity of sigma receptor activation is the inhibition of ion channels, which operates through protein-protein interactions without mediation by G proteins and protein kinases. In addition to modulating various types of voltage-activated K+ channels, the sigma-1 receptor associates with the Kv1.4 K+ channel in posterior pituitary nerve terminals, as well as in Xenopus oocytes. Sigma receptor ligands also modulate N-, L-, P/Q-, and R-type Ca2+ channels in rat sympathetic and parasympathetic neurons. Sigmareceptor ligands modulate cardiac voltage-gated Na+ channels (hNav1.5) in human embryonic kidney 293 (HEK293) cells, COS-7 cells, and neonatal mouse cardiac myocytes. To evaluate the capacity of DMT to induce physiological responses by binding to sigma receptors, we examined the action of DMT on voltage-activated Na+ current.

From:

> Fontanilla D, Johannessen M, Hajipour AR, Cozzi NV, Jackson MB, Ruoho AE. The hallucinogen N,N-dimethyltryptamine (DMT) is an endogenous sigma-1 receptor regulator. Science. 2009;323:934–937.  [[DOI]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.116612)
>   (reference 24 in the article that you cite)

Comment: I would not bother If i haven't been looking for it for 5 days trying solve it, but: Could you please have a glance at my question: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14731/pharmacodynamics-of-ethinyl-estradiol-drospirenone-and-interactions-with-istot