# Pharmacodynamics of Ethinyl estradiol + Drospirenone and interactions with istotertinoin

Tags: pharmacodynamics

Does pharmacodynamics of Ethinyl estradiol + Drospirenone in OCP pills like (Yaz, Yasminelle etc.) while using isotretinoin (Axotret, Roaccutane etc.) is changed? **Does isotretinoin weakens the OCP pill by any means in any situation?**

I know about interaction towards incrase of lipids. The only info I have found is this: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15116059 and results could be translated: *we discovered nothing.*

Comment: I'll give it another look tonight, thanks for editing the advice portion out of the picture

Comment: @jonsca Thank you very much. I will be waiting for your reply.